# Pass paremeter into controller method in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, controller, code-injection

I have a special entity which instantiates with a controller. Duiring request it should be passed into handler's parameter:

```
@Controller
@Scope("session")
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired
    Context context; // this thing should be passed into request.
    //context field from controller should be passed into request parameter
    //in order to set request attributes properly.
    //The instance of CommonRequest class should have reference to the context during
    //mapping HTTP request into CommonRequest object.
    @RequestMapping(value = "/do_smth", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void doSmth(CommonRequest request) {

    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this trick?

Answer (score 1):

```
public void doSmth(CommonRequest request) {
    //context field from controller should be passed into request parameter.
    request.setAttribute("context",context); // if you want to get context back, use Context context = (Context)request.getAttribute("context");
}
```

Comment: Request attributes setters require context object to be set properly. So this object should be passed before request object be parsed by spring.

Comment: @user1453239 : I did not understand, what you want to achieve?

Comment: Each HomeController instace has context object as field. It contains different application data. Also I have CommonRequest class which has getters and setters. CommonRequest's setters has methods like void setId(int id){this.id = id; value = context.getElementById(id); }. When Spring maps incoming request into paremeter this object should contain reference to the context.

Comment: @user1453239 Each HomeController instance?? In Spring by default beans are singleton. i.e. if you do not specify, your HomeController is singleton. Also you are autowiring context which is also singleton.

Comment: I'm new in Spring but as I know each session has an instance of controller. @Scope("Session") attribute is responsible for this.

Comment: Context is using in setters of reqest class. When Spring prosesses the request and maps it into CommonReequest object first it calls setId method. This method sets id of object and puts necessary object into value from context. Then Spring continues process the request and put information into value field, which already been updated during setId method.